# how to convert string to date without time in python

Tags: python, django

I am converting a string to date like this:

```
date=request.GET.get('date','')
    if date:
        date = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        print date
```

This prints:

> 2014-08-08 00:00:00

How can I get the date without the 00:00:00 time?

Comment: `print date.date()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a "datetime" object, hence the time part.

As @jonrsharpe mentioned in his comment, it's

`print date.date()` (output in ISO format)

or `print date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

in your given input format.